# Cannot index timestamp in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to index timestamp in SOLR. I have a field called date_field that is type 'date' in Hive. Once I try to index it using the following setup:

```
<field name="date_field" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
```

Turns out, when I try to index I get an error saying unable to parse date type. Does my underlying field need to be type timestamp? Is there a specific type my data has to be for indexing as type date to work? Making this text-general or string is not a solution because I need to be able to search for date range etc in my UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr expects dates to be formatted in the ISO format: [YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/working-with-dates.html#working-with-dates)

If the content you provide has a different date format, you can convert it using [Update Request Processors](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/update-request-processors.html) that are normally configured in the solrconfig.xml. You can either configure a chain, or - in recent versions of Solr - configure a standalone processor (and reference with *processor* parameter).

The specific processor is ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory and you can find the examples of its usage as [part of the "schemaless mode" processing](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/8.1.0/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/solrconfig.xml#L1146-L1156):

```
<updateProcessor class="solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" name="parse-date">
  <arr name="format">
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd['T'[HH:mm[:ss[.SSS]][z</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd['T'[HH:mm[:ss[,SSS]][z</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm[:ss[.SSS]][z</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm[:ss[,SSS]][z</str>
    <str>[EEE, ]dd MMM yyyy HH:mm[:ss] z</str>
    <str>EEEE, dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss z</str>
    <str>EEE MMM ppd HH:mm:ss [z ]yyyy</str>
  </arr>
</updateProcessor>
```